# css 3d flickering issue in firefox

Tags: css, css-selectors, transform, css-transforms

I have a div that rotae to Y axis to -15deg.It works great in chrome but has areally bad flickering issue firefox.The images inside the div looks scattered and jumpy.The rotation also looks little shaky.

here is the link to codepen demo http://codepen.io/wahidpolin/pen/PZoWbx

```js
$('.chapter').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("flip-to-back")

});
```

```css
.chapters {
  background-color: #ececec;
}
.chapter {
  position: relative;
  height: 266px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 374px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
}
.chapter .front,
.chapter .back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .75s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .75s;
  -o-transition-duration: .75s;
  -ms-transition-duration: .75s;
  transition-duration: .75s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.chapter .front {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.chapter .back {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.chapter .back .chapter-back-top {
  padding: 20px;
}
.chapter .back img,
.chapter .back h3,
.chapter .back h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.chapter .back img {
  width: 48px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
.chapter .back h3,
.chapter .back h4 {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.chapter .back h3 {
  color: #666;
  margin: 5px 0 10px;
}
.chapter .back h4 {
  color: #777;
}
.chapter .back p {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
.chapter:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}
.chapter:hover .back {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.chapter:hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
  transform: rotateY(-15deg);
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
}
.chapter:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(165deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(165deg);
  transform: rotateY(165deg);
}
.chapter .front img {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0 20px;
}
.chapter h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
.chapter h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000;
}
.chapter.flip-to-back .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.chapter.flip-to-back .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="chapters" class="chapters page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="main-heading clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="text-center">Chapters</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="chapter text-center">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
            <h3>Chapter 1</h3>
            <h4>Getting started</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="chapter-back-top clearfix">
              <img src="images/chapters/chapter-img-7.svg">
              <h3>Chapter 1</h3>
              <h4>Getting started</h4>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end of chapters-->
```

Comment: For me it's woking fine in ff 40.0.3

Comment: In FF 42.0 it does seem to work a little better if you also use `-moz-transform-origin` - the borders still get lost but the animation seems smoother. Hopefully this will help point you towards a full solution.

Comment: You're missing a `perspective` (you only have webkit-perspective). The origin of the transform is not the same in Safari and FF. Strangely enough, I also don't get the same picture.

Answer (score 0):

OK so [according to W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) Firefox has supported `transform-origin` since version 16, but it seems to me it hasn't implemented it quite as well as `-moz-transform-origin`. Even with the proprietary version, though, borders seem to disappear in the animation. For me, using a box-shadow instead of a border fixed that:

```
.chapter .front,
.chapter .back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .75s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .75s;
  -o-transition-duration: .75s;
  -ms-transition-duration: .75s;
  transition-duration: .75s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I personally never saw the flicker, though, so I don't know if it'll address that issue for you.